# String to JSON object using dataweave

Tags: dataweave

Here's the Input String:

```js
"
<OuterSet>\n  
  <Set>\n    
    <Id>krypton</Id>\n    
    <Name>Name1</Name>\n  
  </Set>\n  
  <Set>\n    
    <Id>chromium</Id>\n    
    <Name>Name2</Name>\n  
  </Set>\n      
</OuterSet>"
```

I would like the following *JSON* output:

```
[{"Id": "krypton","Name": "Name1"},
{"Id": "chromium","Name": "Name2"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question should be how to convert an XML document contained in a string to JSON really.
You can just do that indicating to DataWeave that the input should be read as an XML, using the read operator. Then select the correct node, with the selector to return an array of all child elements (OutSet.*Set).

The only problem are the strings "\n" which are a representation of new line characters but only add noise to the input. Probably this indicates that the input was converted in some way instead of being generated by an XML toolkit. If you can not get the input without them then you can also eliminate them with the replace operator. If the input is clean XML you can just use the payload.

Example:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
read(payload replace /\\n/ with "", "application/xml").OuterSet.*Set
```

Comment: This solution is going to remove any "\n" from the real XML content as well... This could cause problems in some special cases.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options in dataweave to accomplish the transformations. Here you have to do it in 2 steps:

1. Remove newline by using `replace` operator and replacing `\n` with `""`
2. Use Dataweave `map` operator to loop through the data and map according to you requirements.

Follow below hint:

```
{
payload map {
Id: $.OuterSet.Set.Id,
Name: $.OuterSet.Set.Name
}
```

Comment: This solution replaces any "\n" substrings in the XML content as well.